# how to build a matrix table from a given customer table using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (Customers) where I keep track of how many items customers have bought. For example, see the 1st table in the attached image.
[image]
I want to create a new table like 2nd table in the attached image,

If customer has bought the bundled product, example(flowers+vase), I want to mark them as yes. If not, then just a null value.
I am not sure how to build the 2nd table using the SQL query, any help is appreciated.

This is the SQL i have written,

```
select email
from Customers
where (flowers>0 and vase>0)
```

Comment: what's the datatype of your columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select email 
   , case when flowers>0 and vase>0 then 'yes' else 'No' end as `flowers+vase`
   , case when flowers>0 and sofa>0 then 'yes' else 'No' end as `flowers+sofa`
   , case when sofa>0 and vase>0 then 'yes' else 'No' end as `sofa+vase`
from Customers
```